# How to Plot a Cylinder with GLMakie or Plotlyjs in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to plot a 3-dimensional cylinder.

the parametric equations will be like this:

```
x= r*cos(u)
y=r*sin(u)
z=v
```

with $u \in [0, 2 \pi] $ and $v \in [0, h]$

I am able to create a sphere with GLMakie with this code:

```
using GLMakie

n = 20
θ = [0;(0.5:n-0.5)/n;1]
φ = [(0:2n-2)*2/(2n-1);2]
x = [cospi(φ)*sinpi(θ) for θ in θ, φ in φ]
y = [sinpi(φ)*sinpi(θ) for θ in θ, φ in φ]
z = [cospi(θ) for θ in θ, φ in φ]
surface(x, y, z)
```

but when I try to make a cylinder it fails:

```
using GLMakie
GLMakie.activate!()
set_theme!(backgroundcolor = :white)

# A cylinder of radius r, and height h, having z-axis as symmetry axis
# it is a stack of circles of radius r

r = 5
h = 3
n = 50
θ = LinRange(0, 2pi, 100)
#θ = [0;(0.5:n-0.5)/n;2π]
v = [0;(1:n)/n;h]
x = [r*cos(θ) for θ in θ]
y = [r*sin(θ) for θ in θ]
z = [v for v in v]
surface(x, y, z)
```

can anyone help me?

Thanks

Edited: (still need help for perfecting the plot)

I am now able to plot a cylinder, but it is still hollow on the top and at the bottom, here is the code:

```
using Plots
plotlyjs()

# If x, y, z are vectors then it won't generate a surface
# for a parameterized surface x,y,z should be matrices:
# Check for: typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z)

r = 5
h = 3
m, n =200, 150
u = range(0, 2pi, length=n)
v = range(0, h, length=m)

us = ones(m)*u'
vs = v*ones(n)'
#Surface parameterization
X = r*cos.(us)
Y = r*sin.(us)
Z = vs
Plots.surface(X, Y, Z, size=(600,600), cbar=:none, legend=false)
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the surface you specify has radius of 5, so the interior of the ends is not filled in. You could additionally draw a disc at each end, though.

Comment: Alright I will draw a disk then.. thanks